# "this" reference is not working in nodeJs

Tags: javascript, node.js, unit-testing, mocha.js, sinon-chai

I have two methods in my nodeJs code like

```
function method1(id,callback){
  var data = method2();
  callback(null,data);
}

function method2(){
  return xxx;
}

module.exports.method1 = method1;
module.exports.method2 = method2;
```

for testing function method1 using `Sinon` and `Mocha` i had to `stub` method method2.
 For which it required to call method method2 as

```
function method1(id,callback){
      var data = this.method2();
      callback(null,data);
}
```

**Test Code for this**

```
describe('test method method2', function (id) {
    var id = 10;
    it('Should xxxx xxxx ',sinon.test(function(done){
       var stubmethod2 = this.stub(filex,"method2").returns(data);
       filex.method1(id,function(err,response){
         done();
       })
    })
})
```

using this test cases passed, But the code stopped working with error **this.method2 is not a function.**

Is there any way i can get rid of `this` or `module.exports` which seems buggy.

Please let me know if i missed any other info..

Comment: can you provide full code of test file?

Comment: Did you get this working?

Comment: No its like a trade off either code works or the Test cases work

Answer (score 0):

You are not using module.exports correctly.

Change your code to:

```
export function method1(id,callback){
  var data = method2();
  callback(null,data);
}

export function method2(){
  return xxx;
}
```

And then:

`const MyFuncs = require('path_to_file_with_methods');`

Where you need the methods, called like this:

`MyFuncs.method1(){}`
`MyFuncs.method2(){}`

The docs for [module.exports](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html)

You can also use module.exports in the following manner.

```
module.exports = {
    method1: method1,
    method2: method2
}
```

And require in the same fashion.

**Edit:**

Note that if your version supports it you can also a bit of syntactic sugar in your exports:

```
module.exports = {
    method1,
    method2
}
```

Which holds for object literal notation in general.

Comment: The modules API isn't currently supported (IIRC) in any version of node (officially). I would recommend to use the second option

Comment: Using this throws following error
**SyntaxError: Unexpected reserved word
    at exports.runInThisContext (vm.js:53:16)
    at Module._compile (module.js:414:25)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:442:10)**

Comment: Try the `module.exports = {
    method1: method1,
    method2: method2
}`

Comment: No its throwing a Syntax Error at the declaration Line
**export function method1(id,callback)**

Comment: Can you put more of the relevant code up? How you are exporting, and where you are importing. Plus the tests?

Answer (score 0):

use arrow function to correct this method

in your case

```
function method1(id,callback){
  var data = this.method2();
  callback(null,data);
}
```

can be changed to

```
  let method1 = (id,callback)=>{
    var data = this.method2();
    callback(null,data);
  }
```